Trying to read MPU9250 register with a pointer fails
I am trying to read the "WHO_I_AM" register of the MPU9250 via I2C (using the arduino library from "Asukiaaa").
The function used in the library is "readId" and it needs the adress of the variable i want the register's value to be stored in:
uint8_t MPU9250_asukiaaa::readId(uint8_t *id) {
  beginWireIfNull();
  return i2cRead(address, MPU9250_ADDR_WHOAMI, 1, id);
}

Before even reading the value, i expect it to be 0x71 because the datasheet says the following:

So to see if it's the case, in the main, i use a pointer to store the register's value:
#include <MPU9250_asukiaaa.h>
#include <Adafruit_BMP280.h>

Adafruit_BMP280 bmp; // I2C
MPU9250_asukiaaa mySensor;
uint8_t *Id=NULL;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

#ifdef _ESP32_HAL_I2C_H_ // For ESP32
  Wire.begin(SDA_PIN, SCL_PIN);
  mySensor.setWire(&Wire);
#else
  Wire.begin();
  mySensor.setWire(&Wire);
#endif
  
  bmp.begin(0x76);
  mySensor.beginAccel();
  mySensor.beginGyro();
  mySensor.beginMag();

}

void loop() {

  mySensor.readId(Id);
  Serial.print(*Id,HEX);

  }



With that code, i get 0x61. Which is not correct.
But if instead of a pointer, i used a simple variable and send its adress it will show me 0x71. So in other words, if I do this :
#include <MPU9250_asukiaaa.h>
#include <Adafruit_BMP280.h>

Adafruit_BMP280 bmp; // I2C
MPU9250_asukiaaa mySensor;
uint8_t Id=0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

#ifdef _ESP32_HAL_I2C_H_ // For ESP32
  Wire.begin(SDA_PIN, SCL_PIN);
  mySensor.setWire(&Wire);
#else
  Wire.begin();
  mySensor.setWire(&Wire);
#endif
  
  bmp.begin(0x76);
  mySensor.beginAccel();
  mySensor.beginGyro();
  mySensor.beginMag();

}

void loop() {

  mySensor.readId(&Id);
  Serial.print(Id,HEX);

  }



, it will output 0x71, which is correct. So why is that so ?
Thanks for your help !

"i use a pointer to store the register's value", a pointer does not store a value per se, it points to the location where the value is stored. uint8_t *Id=NULL;  points to a NULL(strictly for C++, it should be nullptr which is a pointer to NULL). The mySensor.readId(&Id); expecting to pass in the pointer pointed to variable id, so that data can be stored in the variable which is declared in uint8_t Id=0;. Further reading Introduction to pointers.
